# Covariant in .net 3.5

Tags: c#, generics, collections, .net-3.5, covariance

I'm learning more about this world.
And in my tests, I found this strange:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void VarianceTest()
    {
        List<string> listValues = new List<string>();
        string[] arrayValues = listValues.ToArray();
        var result = HelperCoVariant.GetTest<int>(listValues); // error to compile
        var result2 = HelperCoVariant.GetTest<int>(arrayValues); // sucess
    }
```

Any Method:

```
public static class HelperCoVariant
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetTest<T>(this IEnumerable<object> t)
    {
        foreach (var item in t)
        {
            yield return (T)item;
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that the. NET 4 that works perfectly because of

> `IEnumerable<out T>`

But why on. NET 3.5, there is this behavior?

Comment: Because C# 3 didn't support covariance or contravariance on generic types...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next-to-last line does not compile because `IEnumerable<T>` does not have the `out` keyword in .NET 2/3/3.5.  Since it doesn't have the `out` keyword, it cannot be treated as covariant in T.

The last line compiles because there *is* array covariance in earlier versions of C#.  See [Covariance and Contravariance in C#, Part Two: Array Covariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx) by Eric Lippert.